# Getting NDVI values from ee.Image using Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am using Google Colab and Earth Engine Python API to extract NDVI value according to date and coordinate. I was trying to follow the guide code from https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/360278; and used `print(get('NDVI'))` with a sample coordinate to see if I can get any value. Instead of getting a value, this is the result that I got, instead of a numeric number.

Is there anything else I can do?

My example:

```
#Define a region of interest as a point and buffer 1km around the area
roi = ee.Geometry.Point([-124.0769, 40.1035]).buffer(1000)

#Get Image from Landsat

image = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT')\
                     .filterDate('2014-01-01', '2014-01-01')\
                     .filterBounds(roi))

#Function from https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/360278

def meanNDVICollection (img,aoi):
  nir = img.select('B5')
  red = img.select('B4')
  ndviImage = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red)).rename('NDVI')

  # Compute the mean of NDVI over the 'region'
  ndviValue = ndviImage.reduceRegion(**{
    'geometry': aoi.getInfo(),
    'reducer': ee.Reducer.mean(),
  }).get('NDVI');  # result of reduceRegion is always a dictionary, so get the element we want

  newFeature = ee.Feature(None, {
      # Adding computed NDVI value
      'NDVI': ndviValue
  }).copyProperties(img, [
      # Picking properties from original image
      'system:time_start'
  ])

  return newFeature
```

My result:

```
ee.ComputedObject({
  "functionInvocationValue": {
    "functionName": "Element.get",
    "arguments": {
      "object": {
        "functionInvocationValue": {
          "functionName": "Element.copyProperties",
          "arguments": {
            "destination": {
              "functionInvocationValue": {
                "functionName": "Feature",
                "arguments": {
                  "metadata": {
                    "dictionaryValue": {
                      "values": {
                        "NDVI": {
                          "functionInvocationValue": {
                            "functionName": "Dictionary.get",
                            "arguments": {
                              "dictionary": {
                                "functionInvocationValue": {
                                  "functionName": "Image.reduceRegion",
                                  "arguments": {
                                    "geometry": {
                                      "functionInvocationValue": {
                                        "functionName": "GeometryConstructors.Polygon",
                                        "arguments": {
                                          "coordinates": {
                                            "constantValue": [
                                              [
                                                [
                                                  -124.0769,
                                                  40.11249886595147
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.08018654971627,
                                                  40.11214066464644
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.0832113930106,
                                                  40.11109458435475
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.08573368559792,
                                                  40.10944392209392
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.08755263737298,
                                                  40.10732010876987
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.08852350016701,
                                                  40.1048922353547
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.08856907708011,
                                                  40.10235358218749
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.0876858411974,
                                                  40.099906227117316
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.08594418480988,
                                                  40.09774495978181
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.08348278913968,
                                                  40.09604178254263
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.0804975711721,
                                                  40.0949322298689
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.07722609182845,
                                                  40.094504591784705
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.073928665595,
                                                  40.09479289545506
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.07086766920538,
                                                  40.095774200623666
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.06828668714203,
                                                  40.09737042293922
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.06639114440881,
                                                  40.099454540880345
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.06533196131409,
                                                  40.10186069488513
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.065193529275,
                                                  40.10439737846875
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.06598696817112,
                                                  40.106862674842496
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.0676492097828,
                                                  40.109060328478726
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.0700479900754,
                                                  40.11081537264418
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.07299236167236,
                                                  40.1119880672073
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.0762478946487,
                                                  40.11248503400732
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                  -124.0769,
                                                  40.11249886595147
                                                ]
                                              ]
                                            ]
                                          }
                                        }
                                      }
                                    },
```

Answer (score 1):

The ouput that you got is expected because you are printing an Earth Engine (i.e. server-side) type object to the screen. To print a `ee` object to your Collab notebook, you must "extract" the information it contains using `.getInfo()`. Example:

```
print(feature.get('NDVI').getInfo())
```

where `fetature` is some `ee.Feature` that is returned from your function `meanNDVICollection`.

GEE guide on client versus server side objects: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server